# Perl parse weblogic config.xml file

Tags: xml, perl, weblogic

I have parsed quite a few xml files using Perl (XML::Simple etc). However, I am having a tough time parsing the config.xml file used in WebLogic. Wondering if anyone has done that before and has some pointers on how to go about it.

Appreciate your guidance.

Thanks,
-Kevin.

Comment: The problem I have is that the config.xml is not a simple "name" : "value" xml file. It does not have a pre-determined number of "levels" or array elements. I'd like to print the file in a format that is easier to read. Among other things, I'd also like to compare the configuration of one WebLogic domain with another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of moving bits and pieces here. What is "easier to read" is in the eye of the beholder.

However, you would benefit from using [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML%3a%3aTwig) which would allow you to deal with the XML however you want.\

Update: Start with the simplest script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings; use strict;
use XML::Twig;

foreach my $xml_file (@ARGV) {
    my $twig = XML::Twig->new;
    $twig->parsefile($xml_file);
    $twig->print;
}
```

And, build from there.

Comment: Thanks Sinan. I have tried Twig a few times but could not get it to correctly parse config.xml. I will try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try LibXML's *parse_file* and *findnodes* methods.  Have a look at [LibXML::XPathContext](http://search.cpan.org/~ilyam/XML-LibXML-XPathContext-0.05/XPathContext.pm).  You can edit the "foo|bar" regex they have to match the nodes you are looking to extract from instead.  This will work if you are parsing from a local file.

If you're parsing a file from a weblogic url, it may require authentication. You can use [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/libwww-perl/lib/LWP.pm), and [HTTP::Request](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTTP-Message-6.06/lib/HTTP/Request.pm) for authentication.  Here's a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25040815/2434565) I posted to one of my questions regarding this except for Jenkins "config.xml" files.