# Perl script to parse Jenkins job (config.xml) files which requires authentication

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, authentication, jenkins

I'm trying to parse Jenkins job "config.xml" files.

Here's one method I tried using **HTTP::Tiny**:

```
use HTTP::Tiny;

my $page = "http://localhost:8080/job/Job_One_Name/config.xml";
system("start $page");  # this loads the xml file in browser successfully

my $wsdlResponse = HTTP::Tiny->new->get($page);
$wsdlResponse->{success} or die print $logger->error_die($!); 
my $wsdlXML = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file($wsdlResponse->{content});

print $wsdlXML;
```

It dies with the error, *"Bad file descriptor"*.

If I comment out that line, the script breaks at the parse_file line with this
error message:

```
Could not create file parser context for file "<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2Fjo
b%2FJob_One_Name/config.xml'/><script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2Fjob%2FJob_One_Name/config.xml');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>                                                                                                                                                    

Authentication required                                                                                               
<!--                                                                                                                  
You are authenticated as: anonymous                                                                                   
Groups that you are in:                                                                                               

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read                                                    
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead                                                      
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer                                                              
-->                                                                                                                   

</body></html>                                                                                                      
                ": Result too large at Job.pm line 67.
```

I've also tried **XML::Twig** and **LibXML->load_xml** and **load_html** from different examples online, but they all die with a error similar to *"Could not create file parser context for file"*, *"Bad file descriptor"*, or *"specify location, string, or IO"*.

Any ideas on what could be the issue?  Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Following the **'Perl LWP example for a scripted client'** from Jenkins' [Authenticating scripted clients](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients), I've successfully authenticated:

```
my $uagent = LWP::UserAgent->new(cookie_jar => HTTP::Cookies->new());
my %options = {'myUserName' => 'myPassword'};
$req = HTTP::Request->new( GET => $serverHost );
$req->authorization_basic( 'myUserName', 'myPassword' );
my $res = $uagent->request($req);

# Check the outcome of the response
print "Result: " . $res->status_line . "\n";
print $res->headers->as_string;
print "\n";
if ( !$res->is_success ) {
    print "Failed\n";
} else {
    print "Success!\n";

    # Parse XML
    my $wsdlResponse = HTTP::Tiny->new->get($page, \%options);
    #$dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location=>$page);     
    #print $dom . "\n";
    my $wsdlXML = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file($wsdlResponse->{content});
    print $wsdlXML;
    #print $res->content, "\n";
}
```

It's still giving me the same **'Authentication required'** error.  I don't know how to use the successfully authorized request to then parse the file.

Comment: _"It dies with the error, "Bad file descriptor"."_ -- ***WHERE***?

Comment: @JimGarrison  at the "die" line, "$wsdlResponse->{success} or die print $logger->error_die($!); "

Comment: What are you trying to grab? The `config.xml` is a well structured XML. There is a RESTful API for much of the information in Jenkins including the job and for individual builds. You can pull information out in JSON, Python, or XML format that way. Click on the REST API link on the bottom of your Jenkins page. Will that help?

Comment: @DavidW. Thanks for the response. I'm just trying to write my own script that does pretty much the same thing as Fetch does in REST API.  The script just prompts for everything instead through the command prompt or shell (job name, nodes, etc.), processes it, and lists everything inside an HTML table (it also includes 'Embeddable Build Status' image for each job). I thought it might come in handy or allow me to customize minor things here and there, but it could be useless in the end.. nonetheless, just something I'm testing and working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to use the authenticated request to output results.  Since the request outputs the xml content as well as the headers response, i.e:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Server: Jetty(8.y.z-SNAPSHOT)
Content-Type: application/xml
Client-Date: Wed, 30 Jul 2014 14:49:12 GMT
Client-Peer: 127.0.0.1:8080
Client-Response-Num: 1

<?xml version... 
<project>
  ....
  ....
</project>
```

I used a regular expression to extract *only* the xml part of the output and save it to file.  From there I used LibXML's *parse_file* method to parse the newly written file.  (I have a separate subroutine that uses the *findnodes* method to extract particular nodes I would like to extract. I didn't post it since this solution handles the authentication I was having trouble with).

**Solution:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;
use Path::Class;
use LWP;
use HTTP::Cookies;

my $serverXmlUrl = "http\://localhost:8080/job/jobName/config.xml";
my $uagent = LWP::UserAgent->new(cookie_jar => HTTP::Cookies->new());
my $request = HTTP::Request->new( GET => $serverXmlUrl );
$request->authorization_basic( 'UserName', 'Password' );
my $result = $uagent->request($request);

if ( !$result->is_success ) {
    print "Failed\n";
} else {
    print "Success!\n";

    # Create new file to write to
    my $dir         = dir(".");
    my $file        = $dir->file("job.xml");
    my $file_handle = $file->openw();
    my $xml_content = $result->as_string; # full result output

    # Regex to store only xml content
    $xml_content =~ s/.*(<\?xml.*)/$1/s; 
    # Save xml_content to file
    $file_handle->print($xml_content);
    $file_handle->close();
    # Parse newly written file
    print "Parsing file... \n";
    my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
    my $doc    = $parser->parse_file($file);
    print $doc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to provide authentication as part of your request.

The reason it works in the browser is most likely that you are already logged in to Jenkins and the credentials are cached in the browser.  Those credentials won't be present when you fetch the URL from your Perl code.

You will need to examine how Jenkins maintains session state (a token/cookie) and go through the same procedure in your Perl code.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar by experimenting with 'firefox' in 'icognito mode' - so I could easily see the relevant cookie.
And then used 'EditThisCookie' or 'cookie.txt export' plugins to export it.
Then I created a cookie in perl using the values from that export.

Eventually I found it easier to not use that interface, and instead use an SSH interface to that server instead.

Comment: I was able to parse the xml using the authenticated request.  I posted the solution.  Thanks for the response, I will try that as well:)